# Inserting Params into Angular Factory

Tags: angularjs

i have a problem i cant resolve (sorry for asking that many questions but angular kills me).

my Controller:

```
friendsApp.controller('friendsController', ['$scope','friendsFactory','secondFactory', function($scope, friendsFactory, secondFactory){

    $scope.girlFriendName = friendsFactory.girlFriend();





    secondFactory.getCity(function(data) {
        $scope.city = data;
        console.log($scope.city[0].Name);
    });

}]);
```

My Factory:

```
friendsApp.factory('secondFactory',  function ($http){

    return {
        getCity: function(callback) {
            // HOW TO GET THE VALUE FROM THE CONTROLLER???
            var value = 5;
            $http.get('http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/' + value).success(callback);
        }
    }

});
```

For Testing purposes i wrote the value manually into the Factory. 
But i dont know how to insert it from the Controller.
Can someone help me? Or push me into the right direction?

Comment: You need to set the value as a factory property.  Then call it from your controller as secondFactory.value.  Try return { some_value: 5, getCity: function(callback)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd pass a variable the same way you're currently passing a callback function:

Controller:

```
secondFactory.getCity(var, function(data) {
    $scope.city = data;
    console.log($scope.city[0].Name);
});
```

which in your factory would be referenced as such:

Factory:

```
return {
    getCity: function(var, callback) {
        alert(var);
        $http.get('http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/' + value).success(callback);
    }
}
```

However, you should use .success() instead of passing a callback function, by having your factory return your entire $http request.

Factory:

```
return {
    getCity: function(var) {
        alert(var);
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/' + value);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
secondFactory.getCity(var).success(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After all these hours i cant seem to see any solutions anymore. It worked fine. Now i can finally go to sleep. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating a bit.  Simply return the promise back to the controller:

In your factory:

```
getCity: function(value) {
  return $http.get('http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/' + value);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
secondFactory.getCity('5').then(function (data) {
    $scope.city = data;
    console.log($scope.city[0].Name);
});
```

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain it the right way. I want the value injected by the controller. For example Controller asks for the city 5 or 6 or 7. How do I get the number from the controller into the factory?

Comment: Sure.  Please accept the answer if that worked out for you (or don't if not).